# Voltage at output pin of a controller

Tags: pic, output, port, pins

I would like to ask a simple question. I do have controller whose  pins are configured were configured as o/p. The controller runs at 3.3v and it's from the Pic18f family of controllers.Why is it that the o/p pin shows only voltage of 2.23v when configured as o/p. Is it the maximum or should it show >3.0 v.

It's been on my mind for some time. Is it a natural thing or some configuration mishap?

I would like your take on this phenomena.

edit:

```
Void main() {
    TRISD=0x00;   

    while(1) {
        PORTEbits.RE2=1;
    }   
}
```

Regarding schematic all the Vdd and Vss pins were connected to 3.3v and gnd respectively.

Comment: It's impossible to say without code and a schematic.

Comment: I haven't used a PIC, but I'd expect a high output to be closer to 3 volts.  Is there anything connected to that output that would be pulling it down?  Any MCU output has a limited current capability, and a load of more than ~10 mA would likely prevent the output from reaching 3 volts.

Comment: Well The Pin has to switch On a Relay. @PeterBennett

Comment: As @PeterBennett pointed out, the load of the relay is what is pulling your voltage down. If you remove the relay and just measure the voltage right on the pin you should see 3.3V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're not disclosing the part number of the chip nor the exact schematic, so it's pretty hard to guess, but I'll try.

Take a typical PIC18F part, the [PIC18F1220](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39605F.pdf). When operating from a 3V supply, the \$V_{OH}\$ of a port pin looks like this:

[image]

You are observing a drop of about 1.07V from Vdd. From the graph, that would typically represent a current draw of about 8mA. So I might guess that you've got about a 200-300 ohm load (to Vss) on the port pin, which is quite a heavy load.

Edit: Given the actual data sheet for the [PIC18F](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39931d.pdf) in question, a curve similar to the above is not provided, however there is a relevant line in the specifications:

The PIC is guaranteed to provide at least 2.4V provided you draw less than 6mA over the -40~85°C temperature range. Which leads us to the conclusion that the load exceeds 6mA by some margin (since it's probably not 85°C and since 2.23V < 2.4V), as previously concluded.

[image]